# Dog Food Eating Issues

Tags: dogs, behavior, diet

I've a Labrador and she is 10 months old. I've has been hand feeding my dog since two months and now she is not eating by herself.

Last week, I was out for three days and my mom kept a bowl of chicken for her to eat and she didn't. My mom is a  vegetarian and she doesn't even touches meat.

My dog ate nothing for three days.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Sounds like you need a veterinarian. Also - don't give them anything with chicken bone in it!! Chicken bone is a choking hazard, and it can splinter and damage your dog's intestines.

Answer (score 2):

Why were you hand feeding her in the first place?

A dog in correct medical condition will not starve to death if there's some food around. First thing to do is to check with your vet.

Then you can try to motivate her, for example if you're giving dry food, add some real chicken or wet food, to give more smell and taste.

Comment: Some puppy training classes can recommend hand feeding your puppy so that they get used to it in socialisation classes, some of our class do it constantly, the rest of us don't.

Answer (score -1):

for 1st treatment give him warm water with sugar
then, Raw egg (duck or chicken) mix it with 1 table spoon of honey for the next 1 hour, once every 2 - 3 hour
and slowly mix the raw egg with his dog food, or just boil the egg and give it to him.
if he don't want his dogfood, try to give some raw meat first

if he start to starve and start to limp, bring him to his doctor